# SWIFT mapeo de JSON

Tags: json, swift, xcode

actualmente tengo el siguiente JSON

```
   {
  "headerRS": {
    "errorCode": 0, 
    "errorDesc": "", 
    "orgChannelId": "", 
    "orgChannelRef": "", 
    "orgMsgId": "", 
    "orgTransactionType": "", 
    "timestamp": ""
  }, 
  "messageRS": {
    "data": [
      {
        "fields": {
          "BranchId": "", 
          "CellPhone": "", 
          "ClientId": "", 
          "ClientType": "", 
          "DocumentId": "", 
          "DocumentType": "", 
          "LastName": " ", 
          "Mail": "", 
          "Name": "", 
          "Namec": "", 
          "Phone": ""
        }, 
        "id": 1
      }
    ], 
    "description": "NO DESCRIPTION ERROR", 
    "errorCode": "0"
  }
}
```

Que me lo devuelve una llamada a un servicio, lo que necesito es poder acceder a los datos dentro de fields

estoy intentando de la siguiente forma

```
 let messageRS = responseJSONDict!["messageRS"] as! [String: Any]
 if let data =  messageRS["data"]  as? [String: Any]{
 }
```

Hasta el messageRS anda perfecto.
Pero siempre el data me devuelve nil, como podria facilmente acceder a la informacion como puedo ponerle al "as" para que se mapee y poder acceder por claves a dichos valores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data es un arreglo de objetos, no un objeto, por lo que lo debes castear a un arreglo

```
 let messageRS = responseJSONDict!["messageRS"] as! [String: Any]
 if let data =  messageRS["data"]  as? [[String: Any]]{
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Te recominedo que uses codable para el mapeo de JSON, te evitaras muchos problemas con la estructura de los JSON, usa este enlace www.json4swift.com, esto te genera los modelos cuando lo tengas donde hagas el request,

```
do{
  let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataResponse.self, from: data)
  let fieldsData = response.messagesRS?.data
```

asumiendo que tienes estos Structs al menos estos dos.

```
    struct DataResponse : Codable {
    let headerRS : HeaderRS?
    let messageRS : MessageRS?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case headerRS = "headerRS"
        case messageRS = "messageRS"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        headerRS = try values.decodeIfPresent(HeaderRS.self, forKey: .headerRS)
        messageRS = try values.decodeIfPresent(MessageRS.self, forKey: .messageRS)
    }
}
struct MessageRS : Codable {
    let data : [Data]?
    let description : String?
    let errorCode : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case data = "data"
        case description = "description"
        case errorCode = "errorCode"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = try values.decodeIfPresent([Data].self, forKey: .data)
        description = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description)
        errorCode = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .errorCode)
    }

}
```